# SVG files not found from imported NPM package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, npm, webpack

I have published a NPM package that I import into another project I am working on. In this package, I am using Webpack and there are multiple SVG files being used inside the React components I am using. When I use this package, I get a 404 not found error relating to the SVG images.

```
GET https://localhost:8080/apps/abc/jspm_packages/npm/@myScope/package_name@1.2.3/lib/assets/icons/menu-button.svg.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Take note that this is a svg file that appears to be coming in as a javascript file which is likely behavior I do not want.

Interestingly, when I load up a Create React App that uses just this package, it loads without error.

My Webpack configuration contins the following module block:

```
module: {
rules: [    
  {
    test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|^(?!.*\.inline\.svg$).*\.svg$/,
    loader: 'url'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
  },
  {
    use: "babel-loader",
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    use: ["file-loader"],
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/
  },
  {
    use: ["url-loader"],
    test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/
  }
]
```

}

I have attempted to include svg inside the url-loader as well as the file-loader with no success.

There is one main react component in this package that is composed of other components that contain the svg files. I import my package and use this component. The app will not load and throw the svg 404 error as shown above. Additionally there is this error message in the console as well:

```
system.src.js:5123 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading https://localhost:8080/apps/abc/jspm_packages/npm/@myScope/package_name@1.2.3/lib/assets/icons/menu-button.svg.js
Error loading https://localhost:8080/apps/abc/jspm_packages/npm/@myScope/package_name@1.2.3/lib/assets/icons/menu-button.svg.js as "../../assets/icons/menu-button.svg" from https://localhost:8080/apps/abc/jspm_packages/npm/@myScope/package_name@1.2.3/lib/react/components/SomeReactComponent.js
```

This probably that there is an issue with the path I am using in my React component that contains the svg. The component takes in the svg like so (because I keep all my svg files inside their own asset folder):

```
var MenuButtonImg = require('../../assets/icons/menu-button.svg');
```

This relative path seems to be an issue but I am unsure if this is the root cause of my issue. I would like to know how I can eliminate this 404 error and successfully load my component in my project.

Comment: try to use `react-svg-loader` to import svg as inline svg

Comment: @OrkhanJafarov I am attempting to use that now but get this error in the console now: SomeComponent.js:17 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react-svg-loader!../../assets/icons/menu-button.svg"

Comment: it seems like it's not installed well, try to `npm i --save react-svg-loader` or clean node_modules and reinstall all again

Comment: I decided to just convert the SVGs into react components since it was easier than dealing with this. Now I can't get my CSS to override the components' styles

Comment: react-svg-loader does "convert the SVGs into react components" tho

Comment: Well Ive manually done it now and when I publish this package and try to use it, it appears the it cannot bring in the cass files since it is attempting to import it as a JS file.